# ArrayField is empty even after serializer.save() (Django and Postgres)

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm trying to save an existing Python list to an ArrayField in Postgres, but when saved it ends up empty. When I print data['questions'] and data['sources'], they both print a populated list (ex. [question1, question2, question3]), but when I print serializer.data, it shows as: **'sources': [] and 'questions': []**

data['conversation']['bot'] works correctly. Hence, the problem might be in the model setup, but I'm unable to figure out what's wrong. I have run py manage.py runserver to migrate changes already but the lists are still empty.

Here's the excerpt from views.py:

```
def histories(request):
  if(request.method == 'POST'):
    data = JSONParser().parse(request)
    serializer = HistorySerializer(data=data)
    if(serializer.is_valid()):
      result = some_python_dictionary
      data['conversation']['bot'] = result['answer']
      data['sources'] = result['sources']
      data['questions'] = result['questions']
      serializer.save()
      return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
import json
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

# Create your models here.
class History(models.Model):
    conversation = models.JSONField()
    sources = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=256), default=list)
    questions = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=256),size=3, default=list)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return json.dumps(self.conversation)
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Histories"
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import routers, serializers, viewsets
from .models import History

class HistorySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = History
        fields = ['conversation', 'sources', 'questions', 'created_at']
```

Comment: you have to populate request.data correctly and pass it to serializer

Comment: check `serilizer.errors` after you call `serializer.is_valid()` that should show you what is wrong with your data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You passed `data` to `serializer = HistorySerializer(data=data)`. Once data has been passed to your serializer, changes made to `data` will actually not be made to your `serializer.data` object which I think is the source of your confusion.

After you validate your serializer by using `.is_valid()`. You can access the data using `serializer.validated_data`. You can change your code a little bit to be:

```html
def histories(request):
  if(request.method == 'POST'):
    data = JSONParser().parse(request)
    serializer = HistorySerializer(data=data)
    if(serializer.is_valid()):
      result = some_python_dictionary
      serializer.validated_data['conversation']['bot'] = result['answer']
      serializer.validated_data['sources'] = result['sources']
      serializer.validated_data['questions'] = result['questions']
      serializer.save()
```

Comment: Adding serializer.validated_data fixed it for me! Thank you so much!